# Range Empty for Dynamic Chart VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a dynamic sourcedata on a chart in VBA as this can vary depending on the data being pulled in via a macro. So far I have:

```
Set Rng = Sheets("Mapping Tables").Range("J13", Sheets("Mapping Tables").Range("J13").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select

    Worksheets("Vintage").Charts("Vintage_1").SetSourceData Rng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

However, when I step through the code in the set range command, my cells are being selected. When I run through the SetSourceData step nothing happens. When I hover over the Rng variable it says = nothing.

I've never really done dynamic charts before but I cannot understand why my range equals nothing when my range is being selected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim obj As ChartObject
    Set Rng = Sheets("Mapping Tables").Range("J13", Sheets("Mapping Tables").Range("J13").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

    Set obj = Worksheets("Vintage").ChartObjects("Vintage_1")
    With obj.Chart
        .SetSourceData Rng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

actually the first line should give you an error, if I'm not mistaken. You cannot set a range to a ".select" statement. 
Try deleting the ".select" at the end

Edit: when you're defining a continuous range (e.g. a table), you can use something cleaner:

```
set Rng = Sheets("Mapping Tables").Range("J13").CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not used currentregion before, however I still can't seem to get my chart to update based on that range, just steps through the code but with no action (no error either).